# Can I know why it doesn't give out the output for below code since there's no any error?

Tags: jdbc

```
package labexercise2;
import java.sql.*;

public class LabExercise2
{
public static void main (String [] args) throws SQLException,   ClassNotFoundException {

 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 System.out.println ("Driver Loaded");
 Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/restaurant?"+ "user=root&password=");
 System.out.println ("Database connected");


Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT MenuID, MenuName, Type, Cuisine FROM menu WHERE Price BETWEEN 7 AND 13");
while (rs.next()){
System.out.println(rs.getString("MenuID") + " : " +
rs.getString("MenuName") + " : "  +     
rs.getString("Type") + " : " +
rs.getString("Cuisine") + " : "  +   
rs.getString("Price"));  }

connection.close();
}
}
```

Can I know why it doesn't give out the output for below code since there's no any error?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You mean to say, you not able to see the fields of table, or none of the println is working????

Comment: It only shows run:
 Driver Loaded
Database connected
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds) in the output panel. I'm using netbeans 8.1

Comment: I'm not able to see the fields of table that should be executed as in executeQuery(). The first two println successfully showed

Comment: put a brekpoint and debug your code. See if your query is returning any values.

Comment: one thing, you not selecting price in query, but you trying to print the price.

Comment: There's no any changes even after I put breakpoint.

Comment: Can I get the correct code to show all the data of 'Type=Foods' with Price between RM7.00 and RM13.00? Help needed :)

Comment: Have you tested your SQL query from a SQL client  (e.g. Squirrel, MySql Workbench)? Does it return any results?

Comment: Are you able to get connection? As I think 3306 is missing.

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed port number in DriverManager.getConnection argument,it should be as following.

```
Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant?"+ "user=root&password=");
```

Comment: can you please print rs object before while loop ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.

Comment: empty result set.?? Sounds like your program code is working fine. See my earlier comment to your original question.

Comment: I think your select query is doubtful. please try the query first in Mysql Workbench. Particularly, I have doubt in your "where condition" to find value from range. check you DB price field has a type "single" or "double".

Answer (score 0):

package labexercise2;
import java.sql.*;

public class LabExercise2
{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 System.out.println ("Driver Loaded");
 Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant?"+ "user=root&password=");
 System.out.println ("Database connected");


Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE Price BETWEEN 7.00 AND 13.00");
while (rs.next()){
System.out.println(rs.getString("MenuID") + " : " +
rs.getString("MenuName") + " : "  +     
rs.getString("Type") + " : " +
rs.getString("Cuisine") + " : "  +   
rs.getString("Price"));  }

conn.close();
```

}
    }

Answer (score 0):

can you try following code instead `connection.close();`

```
if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }

        if (connection!= null) {
            connection.close();
        }
```

Comment: I can't get the output even after I try it :(

Answer (score 0):

i have mocked and tested your code, it's working for me as explained below.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class LabExercise2 {

public static void main (String [] args) throws SQLException,   ClassNotFoundException {

 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 System.out.println ("Driver Loaded");
 Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/restaurant?"+ "user=root&password=root");
 System.out.println ("Database connected");


Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE Price BETWEEN 7 AND 13");
while (rs.next()){
System.out.println(rs.getString("MenuID") + " : " +
rs.getString("MenuName") + " : "  +     
rs.getString("Type") + " : " +
rs.getString("Cuisine") + " : "  +   
rs.getLong("Price"));  }

connection.close();
}
```

}

Comment: seriously? Do u created database? How is it possible?

Comment: Yes, I do created small DB sample to debug the issue.